# Не работает подсветка синтаксиса в pom.xml файлах в intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Не работает подсветка синтаксиса в `pom.xml` файлах в `intellij idea`.

Если изменить название файла, то подсветка символа появляется. Пробовал `intellij` idea 14, 15 версии.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, в чем может быть проблема и где найти соответствующие настройки?

[image: отображение pom файла]

Comment: у вас же другой файл на скриншоте открыт, не?

Comment: Открыт как раз файл, подсвеченный слева синим. Но это не важно, все файлы с названием pom.xml не подсвечиваются.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще подсветка в Settings -> Editor -> File Types. Возможно, что-то было сбито. Или добавлен новый тип с .xml поверх старого XML.
Если идея глючит сделай File->Invalidate Caches And Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Нажми правой кнопкой мыши на файле в Idea, выбери Override Type File и выбери разрешения файла, после этого заработает синтаксис.